# How does the Dropbox Datastore API differ from Parse?

Tags: dropbox, parse-platform, dropbox-api

How does the [Dropbox Datastore API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore) differ from similar offerings like [Parse](https://parse.com/)?  One difference that I see is that my users pay for server storage instead of me.  Are there other differences?

Comment: It's a very interesting development. Maybe your question is not specific enough (why it gets downvotes) but in general you could state that Dropbox already has millions of users. That makes it more easy to identify an use it. On the other side users search a solution, not a storage place, so the app storage location is not the first relevant factor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a Dropbox engineer who worked on the Datastore API, and know about the Parse API only indirectly.  Weigh my opinion appropriately.  Major differences I know of (pro and con):

- Dropbox Datastores are free to the developer, and free the user for the first 5MB per-app (after which their Dropbox quota applies).  Parse charges developers based on how many API requests they’re making.
- Parse has minimal offline support, while Dropbox has full offline operation. With Dropbox, if the developer modifies data while offline, those modifications will be reflected in subsequent queries (with Parse, those changes are not reflected). Dropbox provides on-device query logic (unlike Parse) so that apps can continue to generate the views they need to, even when there’s no Internet available. In addition, Parse does not provide conflict resolution or querying offline.
- Parse provides the ability to share data between users, and global data for all users of the app.  Dropbox Datastores only support per-user data (for each app) for now (sharing is on the roadmap).

Answer (score 3):

I would also add that:

Parse is full feature of backend of as service. You can find a pretty complete list of the other player in this field: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backend_as_a_service. They provide feature like:

- Data service
- User registration/auth
- Push notification
- Social

The dropbox Datastore APIs is more focusing on data services. (You also got the User part for free too?) Also it works full offline.

Answer (score 2):

The Parse framework can store data that can be ready by any user in the application.

The Dropbox datastore, store data for each user, and you can't accesss data from other user. That's the main difference.

Comment: Parse supports authentication through [Facebook and Twitter](https://parse.com/products/social).

Answer (score 1):

So easy to get lost in this since you have to read between the lines. My take is that with Datastore you are working with objects stored offline locally as json. I'm hoping they will soon release a Xamarin Android component - they released an IOS component last month. Since Xamarin targets both Android and IOS and Winphone, who knows why they made a dedicated IOS DLL for Xamarin but I digress. With Parse, it appears to me their intent is the always-connected-device. Sure you can save queries locally and you can save (save eventually) locally where Parse will push to the server when it is connected. But saving "eventually" and saving queries for offline work is a different design than just saving and letting Parse do it all in the background for you - which it does not unless I have missed something that would make this attractive to me. I cannot see Parse useable for devices that you know will be sometimes-connected, without a lot of code to make this happen and sync.